# SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ Stripe (in target 'Stripe' from project 'Pods')

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, stripe-payments

All of sudden today I start getting this error when do the ios build from xcode or run this command yarn ios

The following build commands failed:
SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ Stripe (in target 'Stripe' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)

This is my podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '16.0'
target 'BorroUp' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  target 'BorroUpTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Stripe', '21.3.1'
  use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
           target.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
        end
    end
  end
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: can you try `pod update` then `pod install`?

Comment: also try to clear cached files with `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: @hmunoz that did not work.

Comment: Still having the issue, did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

This issue seems to be related to XCode 14 beta 1.
fixed this issue by remove casting to pkDidSelectShippingMethodSignature, so the code looks like this:

```
let pk_didSelectShippingMethod = #selector(
            PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate.paymentAuthorizationController(
                _:didSelectShippingMethod:handler:))
```

Source:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/1973