# React native run-ios fails. ios build fails. Android works. Xcode upgraded to 14 is only change

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

No code changes on my side. Xcode update happened and now the build fails. Android works just fine. here is the error I get:

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
SwiftEmitModule normal x86_64 Emitting\ module\ for\ Stripe (in target 'Stripe' from project 'Pods')
SwiftCompile normal x86_64 Compiling\ AddPaymentMethodViewController.swift,\ AfterpayPriceBreakdownView.swift,\ Analytic.swift,\ Analytic+Payments.swift,\ APIRequest.swift,\ ApplePayHeaderView.swift,\ Async.swift,\ BackwardsCompatibleColors.swift,\ BillingAddressEditView.swift,\ BottomSheet3DS2ViewController.swift,\ BottomSheetViewController.swift,\ CardDetailsEditView.swift,\ CardScanningView.swift,\ CheckboxButton.swift,\ CheckboxElement.swift,\ ChoosePaymentOptionViewController.swift,\ CircularButton.swift,\ ConfirmButton.swift,\ ContainerView.swift,\ DefaultPaymentMethodStore.swift,\ DimmedView.swift,\ Dropd
```

package.json:

```
"@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.1.4",
```

i saw some other folks got this error and it solved for them to update to ios 14.0. i did the same but does not seem to solve my issue. here is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '14.0'
```

xcode version:
Version 14.0.1 (14A400)

Comment: Hello! A couple possibilities: have you already tried some general reset steps like clearing out your pods and running `pod update` and `pod install`?  Does the solution to this similar-looking Stripe / Xcode 14 question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73732863/962986) change anything?

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading stripe to 0.19.0 in package.json, then run "pod update Stripe" in the ios folder.

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/1183#issuecomment-1299967570